# Problem installing LMMS using DNS Sound PPA

Tags: 12.04, ppa

I would like to install the newest LMMS version to date, which is to say LMMS 0.4.13, as mentioned in the Launchpad PPA page DNS Sound (https://launchpad.net/~dns/+archive/sound), which keeps up to date packages of a lot of awesome music software on Linux. As I'm using several of them, I added the PPA in Software Sources; it was successful but, strangly, I can't get LMMS 0.4.13 in Synaptic. I get 'lmms' version 0.4.10 and 'lmms-common' 0.4.13, which causes unresolved dependencies, as:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lmms : Depends: lmms-common (= 0.4.10-2ubuntu1) but 0.4.13-stable.git.2225-2~precise1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to fix this?

I'm using a freshly updated Ubuntu, 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent the better part of today looking for an answer to this, and it seems this is a build error with the DNS/Sound PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~dns/+archive/sound/+build/3324256

I'm a linux noob so I don't know if that is helpful or where to go from here, but I too would like to know how to get the latest LMMS up and running.

Comment: How about the IRIE Shinsuke PPA? I haven't tested it, just offering it as an alternative.
https://launchpad.net/~irie

Comment: Thanks to both. Irie PPA works very well! I finally managed to get the latest LMMS version.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed now!